# Excel Worksheets VBA

Tags: vba, excel

another Excel 2013/VBA question...

I'm trying to set up a userform in VBA which pulls data from a specified worksheet. I've got the form set up and I am extracting the data from the cells withou any issues barr one. The form is pulling the data from whichever sheet is active in the background. I can't workout were i'm going wrong but I am very knew to Excel/VBA.

My first form (`frmMenu`) is a simple radio button group which I use to select the desired zone and set zoneChoice String to the correct value. the main (`frmNSSMain`) form is then loaded adn with the code i have put below, i am expecting it to pull data of of either of the two sheets in the workbook at present, "Central" and "SE".

Unfortunately, the data is pulled off of whichever is the active sheet at run time, and not the one seletced by the user. im guessing the problem is from the activate function, `Set sh = line`. Any help appreciated.

Code from `frmMenu`

```
Public zoneChoice As String

Private Sub btnLoadMain_Click()
If Me.optCentral Then
    zoneChoice = "Central"
    frmNSSMain.Show
    ElseIf Me.optSE Then
    zoneChoice = "SE"
    frmNSSMain.Show
    'ElseIf Me.optSNI Then
    'frmNSSMain.zoneChoice = "SNI"
    'frmNSSMain.Show
    'ElseIf Me.optSW Then
    'frmNSSMain.zoneChoice = "SW"
    'frmNSSMain.Show
    Else:
    msg = MsgBox("You must choose a Zone from the right hand side before continuing!", vbCritical)
End If
End Sub
```

Code from `frmNSSMain`

```
Public Sub UserForm_Activate()
' Initialize worksheet variables
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(frmMenu.zoneChoice)
x = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
y = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("R2:R" & x), "")

'K holds row count based on data in Column A
k = sh.Range("A2", sh.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

'Disable discard, submit and no contact buttons until data is loaded
btnSubmit.Enabled = False
btnDiscard.Enabled = False
btnNoContact.Enabled = False
txtQ1Score.Enabled = False
txtQ2Score.Enabled = False
txtContactNumber.MaxLength = 11
lblOne.Caption = frmMenu.zoneChoice
End Sub


Private Sub btnRetrieve_Click()

    ' Check Data for NSS surveys is available, if so retrieve data, else show error message
    If y > 0 Then

        'Select random row
        aRandNum = Int((k - 2) * Rnd + 2)

        'Set global variable aRow to held selected row
        aRow = Replace(Str(aRandNum), " ", "")

        'Get Area
        areaName = Replace("D" & Str(aRandNum), " ", "")
        txtArea.Text = Range(areaName).Value

        'Get Establishment
        establishmentName = Replace("E" & Str(aRandNum), " ", "")
        txtEstablishment.Text = Range(establishmentName).Value

        'Get End User Name
        endUserName = Replace("F" & Str(aRandNum), " ", "")
        txtName.Text = Range(endUserName).Value

        'Get End User Contact Number
        endUserTelNum = Replace("G" & Str(aRandNum), " ", "")
        txtContactNumber.Text = Replace(Range(endUserTelNum).Value, " ", "")
        txtContactNumber.Enabled = True
        txtContactNumber.Locked = False

        'Get Job Description
        jobDescription = Replace("I" & Str(aRandNum), " ", "")
        txtJobDescription.Text = Range(jobDescription).Value

        'Get contractor
        contractorName = Replace("H" & Str(aRandNum), " ", "")
        txtContractor.Text = Range(contractorName).Value

        'Get job number
        jobNumber = Replace("C" & Str(aRandNum), " ", "")
        txtJobNumber.Text = Range(jobNumber).Value

        ' reported by, contact number, contractor, job description, comments, raised by, survey by,

        ' Disable get NSS data button after retrieval and activate other discard, submit and no contact
        btnSubmit.Enabled = True
        btnDiscard.Enabled = True
        btnNoContact.Enabled = True
        btnRetrieve.Enabled = False
        txtQ1Score.Enabled = True
        txtQ2Score.Enabled = True

        ElseIf y < 1 Then

        Dim result As String
        result = MsgBox("No NSS data available. Please inform Management Team.", vbCritical)

    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Question resolved. Stupid simple mistake like most of the annoying ones are...

`sh.Activate` missing from UserForm_Activate

Doh...